# How Do I Fix Tuple Iindex Out Of Range

Tags: python, sqlite

Im getting this error when trying to display results at the bottom of every function. I have looked around the internet for ages and come seem to come to a fix, also my display column data function doesnt work completely and I dont know why it just displays the name of the column several times can anyone help?

```
# Created By Dante 1/07/19, This Program Will Access A Cpu Database And Will Allow You To Create Entries, Read Data And Sort Relevant Data.
# 
import sqlite3 # Imports Sql Into The Program
with sqlite3.connect("Cpus.db") as connection: # Verifing Connection To The Database
        print(connection)
        c = connection.cursor() # Defines C As The Connection To The Cursor

def read_data(connection):
    c = connection.cursor()
    columns = ("Manufacture, Name_, Cost, Speed_GHz, Cores, Threads") # Columns Variable That Holds Column Names
    while True: #Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break     
            try:
                    display_choice = int(input("How Would You Like To Display The Data? \nType 1 For All Data \nType 2 For Column Data ")) # Asking For Input
            except:
                    print("Please Type 1 Or 2")
                    continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
            if display_choice > 2: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                    print("Please Type A Valid Input Number")
            elif display_choice < 1: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                    print("Please Type A Valid Input Number")
            elif display_choice == 1: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Cpus")
            elif display_choice == 2: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                    read_column_data(connection)
    results = c.fetchall() # Takes The Fetch All Results Command And Turns It Into A Simple Results Variable Making It Callable 
    for i in results:
            print(i[0])
            print(i[1])
            #print("Name: {0:1} Time: {0:1}".format(i[0],i[1])) # Formats The Results And Displays Them

def read_column_data(connection):
        while True: #Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break     
                try:
                        columns = ("Manufacture, Name_, Cost, Speed_GHz, Cores, Threads") # Columns Variable That Holds Column Names
                        column_selection = int(input("What Column Would You To Display Data From? \nType 1 For Manufacture \nType 2 For Name_ \nType 3 For Cost \nType 4 For Speed_GHz \nType 5 For Cores \nType 6 For Threads ")) # Asking For Input
                        break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
                except:
                        print("Please Type 1 Or 2")
                continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
        if column_selection > 6: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                print("Please Type A Valid Input Number") 
        elif column_selection < 1: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                print("Please Type A Valid Input Number")
        elif column_selection == 1: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                column_selection = "Manufacture"  
        elif column_selection == 2: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                column_selection = "Name_"
        elif column_selection == 3: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                column_selection = "Cost"
        elif column_selection == 4: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                column_selection = "Speed_GHz"
        elif column_selection == 5: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                column_selection = "Cores"
        elif column_selection == 6: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                column_selection = "Threads"
        sql_query = ("SELECT ? FROM Cpus") # Sql Query Held As A String So That It Can Be Executed To The Database When Required
        #tuple_insert = (column_selection_1)
        c.execute(sql_query,(column_selection,)) # Executes The Sql Query And The Tuple To The Cursor That Is Defined As C
        results = c.fetchall() # Takes The Fetch All Results Command And Turns It Into A Simple Results Variable Making It Callable 
        for i in results: # For Loop For Displaying Data
                print("Manufacture: {0:1}Name_: {0:1}Cost: {}Speed_GHz: {}Cores: {}Threads: {}".format(i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5],i[6])) # Formats The Results And Displays Them

def order_data(connection):
    c = connection.cursor()
    columns = ("Manufacture, Name_, Cost, Speed_GHz, Cores, Threads") # Columns Variable That Holds Column Names
    while True: #Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break     
            try:
                    print(columns)
                    column_select = int(input("What Column Would You Like To Order Data From?\nType 1 For Manufacture\nType 2 For Name_\nType 3 For Cost\nType 4 For Speed_GHz\nType 5 For Cores\nType 6 For Cores ")) # Asking For Input
            except:
                    print("Please Type A Number")
                    continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
            if column_select > 6: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                    print("Please Type The Number Of The Column You Want To Order Cpu Data From")
            elif column_select < 1: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                     print("Please Type The Number Of The Column You Want To Order Cpu Data From")
            else:
                break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop        
    while True: #Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break     
            try:
                    order_method = int(input("How Would You Like To Order The Data? \nType 1 For Descending \nType 2 For Ascending "))
            except:
                    print("Please Type A Number")
                    continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
            if order_method > 2: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                    print("Please Type 1 Or 2 To Order The Data? ")
            elif order_method < 1: # An If Statement That Prints A Reply That Makes The User Enter A Valid Reply
                    print("Please Type 1 Or 2 To Order The Data? ")
            else:
                break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
    if column_select == 1: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            column_select = "Manufacture"
    elif column_select == 2: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            column_select = "Name_"
    elif column_select == 3: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            column_select = "Cost"
    elif column_select == 4: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            column_select = "Speed_GHz"
    elif column_select == 5: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            column_select = "Cores"
    elif column_select == 6: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            column_select = "Threads"
    elif order_method == 2: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            order_method = "ASCE"
    elif order_method == 1: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
            order_method = "DESC"
    sql_query = ("SELECT ? FROM Cpus ORDER BY ?,? ") # Sql Query Held As A String So That It Can Be Executed To The Database When Required
    tuple_insert = (column_select, column_select, order_method)
    c.execute(sql_query,tuple_insert) # Executes The Sql Query And The Tuple To The Cursor That Is Defined As C
    results = c.fetchall() # Takes The Fetch All Results Command And Turns It Into A Simple Results Variable Making It Callable 
    for i in results: # For Loop For Displaying Data
            #print(i)
            print("Manufacture: {0:1}Name_: {0:1}Cost: {}Speed_GHz: {}Cores: {}Threads: {}".format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5]))

def create_entry(): # This Function Creates An Entry To The Database
    with sqlite3.connect("Cpus.db") as connection:
        c = connection.cursor() 
        append_table_manu = input("What Is The Manufacture Name Of The Cpu You Are Adding? ") # Asking For Input
        append_table_cpu = input("What Is The Name Of Your Cpu You Are Adding? ") # Asking For Input
        while True: #Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break        
                try:
                        append_table_cost = int(input("How Much Does The Cpu You Are Adding Cost? (E.g $99)"))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
                if append_table_cost > 100000:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Cost Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_cost < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Cost Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                    break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
        while True: # Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break        
                try:
                        append_table_speed = int(input("What Is The Speed Of The Cpu That You Are Adding?, (E.g 2.4) "))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
                if append_table_speed > 7: 
                        print("Please Type The Actual Speed Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_speed < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Speed Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                        break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
        while True: #Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break        
                try:
                        append_table_cores = int(input("How Many Cores Does The Cpu You Are Adding Have? "))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
                if append_table_cores > 16:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Core Amount Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_cores < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Core Amount Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                        break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
        while True: # Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break      
                try:
                        append_table_threads = int(input("How Many Threads Does The Cpu That You Are Adding Have?, (E.g 99) "))
                except:
                        print("Please Type A Number")         
                        continue # Continues At The Beginning Of The Loops Until Valid Input
                if append_table_threads > 10000:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Thread Amount Of Your Cpu")
                elif append_table_threads < 0:
                        print("Please Type The Actual Thread Amount Of Your Cpu")
                else:
                        break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
        tuple_insert = (append_table_manu, append_table_cpu, append_table_cost, append_table_speed, append_table_cores, append_table_threads) # This Is Value Holder That Is Used To Insert Input Value Into THe Sql Query
        sql_query = ("INSERT INTO Cpus (Manufacture,Name_,Cost,Speed_GHz,Cores,Threads) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)") # Sql Query Held As A String So That It Can Be Executed To The Database When Required
        c.execute(sql_query,tuple_insert) # Executes The Sql Query And The Tuple To The Cursor That Is Defined As C
        results = c.fetchall() # Takes The Fetch All Results Command And Turns It Into A Simple Results Variable Making It Callable 
        print(tuple_insert)
        for i in results: # For Loop For Displaying Data
                print("Manufacture: {0:1}Name_: {0:1}Cost: {}Speed_GHz: {}Cores: {}Threads: {}".format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5]))


while True: # Puts Everything Below In A Loop Until It Hits A Break     
        option_1 = int(input("What Would You Like To Do To The Cpu Database? \nType 1 For Creating An Entry \nType 2 For Ordering Data\nType 3 For Displaying Relevant Data ")) #Asks The User For Input And Stores The Value
        if option_1 == 1: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                create_entry() # Runs The Create Entry Function If The User Inputs 1 Into The First Question
        elif option_1 == 2: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                order_data(connection) # Runs The Create Entry Function If The User Inputs 2 Into The First Question
        elif option_1 == 3: # An If Statement That Does Something, Dependant On The Users Input/Answer
                read_data(connection) # Runs The Create Entry Function If The User Inputs 3 Into The First Question
        break # Breaks Out Of The While True Loop
```

I just get Tuple Index out of range and ive tried rearranging number but nothing seems to work

Comment: Print your `results` and in the loop print `i` (as a whole) or `len(i)` to see its length.

Answer (score 0):

The proximate cause of the error in `read_column_data` is because the query `sql_query = ("SELECT ? FROM Cpus")` is selecting *one* column from Cpus table, but trying to display *six* columns here:

```
print("Manufacture: {0:1}Name_: {0:1}Cost: {}Speed_GHz: {}Cores: {}Threads: {}".format(i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5],i[6])) # Formats The Results And Displays Them
```

[There's a similar problem in `order_data` here `sql_query = ("SELECT ? FROM Cpus ORDER BY ?,? ")`]

But there is an overriding flaw:  this `sql_query = ("SELECT ? FROM Cpus")` is not returning what you want or expect. One cannot use parameter substitution for column names (or table names). So in this case it is returning the *string literal* of the column name.

Correcting these problems will naturally uncover other problems. Suggest you start with selecting an verifying the results and then move on to displaying them.

You may want to study [Row Objects in the python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects). That may help with the read_column_data problem because then you can access the results by key.

You will have to construct the query in `order_data` differently because you cannot use parameter substitution for the ORDER BY clause.

Good luck!